# Upgrading to Visual Studio 2012/13 - test lists

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In upgrading a large application solution from VS2008 Developer to VS2012/13 Pro, I have a monumental problem - VS2012 onwards no longer supports test lists, and I have some 11,000 tests in various test lists so that they can be executed selectively.

Passing over the question of why on earth MS saw fit to drop this genuinely useful and easy to use feature in favour of the cumbersome TestCategory attribute approach, I have two questions:

1. Is there a tool available that can be used to 'migrate' tests the are in one or other test list to the testcategory approach? (We could write one, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel because we surely are not the first to be faced wiht this hurdle).
2. Once tests have been taggged with one or more TestCategory attribute, how can you easily see in Visual Studio which tests belong to a particular TestCategory? In other words, how do you manage test categories?